# Syntax error on bash for running python script

Tags: python, bash, terminal, shebang

I want run this simple python code int terminal:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print('Hello world')
```

I saved this script as hello.py

I go to terminal to write down:

```
$ chmod +x hello.py
```

then I click enter. This is to allow permission to be granted. Terminal then showed me this:

```
-bash: $: command not found
```

Ok...I then write down the path to hello.py:

```
$ /Users/myname/Documents/MyPythonScripts/hello.py
```

I press enter. I was expecting terminal to print out hello world but to my horror, terminal show this:

```
/Users/myname/Documents/MyPythonScript/hello.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `'Hello world''
/Users/hadi/Documents/MyPythonScript/hello.py: line 3: `print('Hello world')'
```

What's wrong here?

Btw, Running on macOS 10.13.3 and Python 3.6.3

Comment: Did you actually type the `$` sign at the start of the line? If you saw it in examples, it is only the prompt, it's not part of the command. So simply enter `chmod +x hello.py`

Comment: It seems that your first line (the shebang line, starting with `#!`) isn't recognized. It could happen if your line endings are not Unix '\n', but Windows line endings. What editor did you create your script with?

Comment: Nope, I only enter `chmod +x hello.py`.

Comment: Oh, I got it now. I have a blank space in my python script before `#!/usr/bin/env python`. Sorry to waste your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this line:

```
-bash: $: command not found
```

tells that you've executed the "$" which is not right.

Your command to set permissions should look like this:

```
chmod +x hello.py
```

Another comment is that the shebang line should be without space:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```